# Convergence in distribution of indicator function

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ random variables with $n^{1/2}(\bar{Y}_{n} - \mu ) \xrightarrow{D} iid \mathcal{N}(0,\,\sigma^{2}).$

Show
$g_{n}(x_n(c))=1[n^{1/2}\frac{(\bar{Y}_{n} - \mu )}{\sigma} \leq c] \xrightarrow{D} 1[Z \leq c], \quad
Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ where $c$ is some deterministic value (and $1$ the indicator function).

Any help on this (in the paper it says distributional approximation)? As far as I see I cannot apply the continuous mapping theorem. Does the sequence converge almost surely, if yes why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define 
$$X_n:=\sqrt[] {n} \frac{\overline{Y_n}-\mu} {\sigma} $$
what is given is equivalent with $X_n\stackrel{D} {\to} Z$, with $Z\sim\mathcal N (0,1)$.

The indicator function is either zero or one, so for a fixed $c$ one has:

$$P(\mathbf{1}_{\{X_n\leq c\}}=1)=P(X_n\leq c)\stackrel{}{\to} P(Z\leq c) =P(\mathbf{1}_{\{Z\leq c\}} = 1)$$
Similarly 
$$P(\mathbf{1}_{\{X_n\leq c\}}=0) \stackrel{}{\to} P(\mathbf{1}_{\{Z\leq c\}} = 0)$$
Hence $$\mathbf{1}_{\{X_n\leq c\}}\stackrel{D} {\to} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z\leq c\}}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please, could you just check the following argument for another function: Consider $g_{n}(x_n(c))= \Phi(c-X_n) \xrightarrow{D} \Phi(c-Z)$ with the notation from above. Is it enough to say that due to the continuous mapping theorem ($\Phi(\cdot)$ is continuous) the function converges in distribution?

Comment: @user483161 yes